# Enumeration of Regular Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Fix numbers n,k.  Is there a closed formula known for the number of k-regular graphs consisting of n edges?  I have a method of enumerating k-regular graphs on n edges, and would like to have a number to compare the algorithm against.

Comment: I don't think there's any closed form formula, but you can compare your results with the data in OEIS, such as here:  http://oeis.org/A005638 (for 3-regular graphs) or here:  http://oeis.org/A051031. This is indexed by the number of vertices, not edges, but of course for fixed k this is the same up to a factor of k/2.

Comment: See the answers to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there

Comment: @Gwyn Whieldon Is it possible to access your work some how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no, but I would consult the following link:

http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html

which contains tables of the sums of the numbers you are interested in. The author is very generous with sharing data that is not posted online.