# How many $p$-regular graphs with $n$ vertices are there?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose that there are $n$ vertices, we want to construct a regular graph with degree $p$, which, of course, is less than $n$. My question is how many possible such graphs can we get?

Comment: Why the "of course"?

Comment: Because he defines "graph" as "simple graph", I am guessing.

Comment: This question appeared before on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22089/enumeration-of-regular-graphs/22109#22109

Answer (score 37, accepted):

McKay and Wormald conjectured that the number of simple $d$-regular graphs of order $n$ is asymptotically 
$$\sqrt 2 e^{1/4} (\lambda^\lambda(1-\lambda)^{1-\lambda})^{\binom n2}\binom{n-1}{d}^n,$$
where $\lambda=d/(n-1)$ and $d=d(n)$ is any integer function of $n$ with $1\le d\le n-2$ and $dn$ even.

Bender and Canfield, and independently Wormald, proved this for bounded $d$ in 1978, and Bollobás extended this to $d=O(\sqrt{\log n})$ in 1980.

McKay and Wormald proved the conjecture in 1990-1991 for $\min\{d,n-d\}=o(n^{1/2})$ [1], and $\min\{d,n-d\}>cn/\log n$ for constant $c>2/3$ [2].  These remain the best results.

The gap between these ranges remains unproved, though the computer says the conjecture is surely true there too.  The formula apart from the $\sqrt2e^{1/4}$ has a simple combinatorial interpretation, and the universality of the constant $\sqrt2e^{1/4}$ is an enigma crying out for an explanation.

Incidentally this conjecture is for labelled regular graphs. For isomorphism classes, divide by $n!$ for $3\le d\le n-4$, since in that range almost all regular graphs have trivial automorphism groups (references on request). For $d=0,1,2,n-3,n-2,n-1$, this isn't true.

[1] Combinatorica, 11 (1991) 369-382. http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/nickcount.pdf

[2] European J. Combin., 11 (1990) 565-580. http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/highdeg.pdf

ADDED in 2018:  The "gap between those ranges" mentioned above was filled by Anita Liebenau and Nick Wormald [3]. Another proof, by Mikhail Isaev and myself, is not ready for distribution yet.

[3] https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08373

Comment: Is there an asymptotic value for all d-regular graphs on n vertices (not necessarily simple)?

Comment: @Amudhan: The sparse case is here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4218 .

Comment: I am sorry, I am a bit confused about, what is the meaning of $d=d(n)$, why is it a function? is $d$ not fixed before hand ?

Comment: @SagarM  $d$ could be fixed, but suppose you want the number of regular graphs with $n$ vertices and degree $d=n/2$?  Then $d$ is not fixed. The most general case is to take $d$ to be a function of $n$.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it.

Answer (score 6):

There is no closed formula (that anyone knows of), but there are asymptotic results, due to Bollobas, see
A probabilistic proof of an asymptotic formula for the number of labelled regular graphs (1980)
by B Bollobás (European Journal of Combinatorics)
or Random Graphs (by the selfsame Bollobas).

Answer (score 4):

Looking up OEIS, some related sequences are [A005176](http://oeis.org/A005176) for the number of non-isomorphic regular graphs on $n$ vertices, and [A005177](http://oeis.org/A005177) for the number non-isomorphic connected regular graphs on $n$ vertices.

Answer (score 1):

And 'of course', if you really want those graphs you might have a look at genreg by Markus Meringer: http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html