# Isomorphic regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

How many non-isomorphic classes of regular graphs on $(2n+1)^{m}$ vertices with $m(2n+1)^{m}$ edges with vertex degree $2m$, where $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ are there? Is there a classification known? Can there can be more than one such class (that is are they all isomorphic)?

Is there an example of such non-isomorphic graphs if there are any?

Comment: Since for regular graphs, number of vertices times degree is twice the number of edges, your condition implies $m=1$? Either there is a typo or this looks like homework.

Comment: @Chris this is not a hw. Corrected!

Comment: If you don't assume connected, then there are many non-isomorphic examples.  For example, for $m=1$ and $n=3$ the 7-cycle and the disjoint union of a 4-cycle and a 3-cycle are not isomorphic.  

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asymptotic number of $m$-regular graphs on $N$ vertices is well understood and can be found, for example, in Bollobas' Random Graphs (the argument uses Bollobas' "configuration model"). With probability $1$ a graph has no automorphisms, so this is also the number of isomorphism classes as long as $N$ is large. In your case $N=(2n+1)^m.$ So, for a reasonably sized $n$ (since yours is a natural number, $n>0$ should be fine), if you pick two random graphs, they will be non-isomorphic.

Comment: Degree at least 3 is needed. Also, you might like to divide by $N!$ to convert the asymptotic number of labelled graphs into the asymptotic number of isomorphism classes. This is ok since the number of graphs grows faster than $N!$. In my answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730 I surveyed what is known about this enumeration problem.

Answer (score 3):

For the connected case see http://oeis.org/A068934.

For example, there are two non-isomorphic connected 3-regular graphs with 6 vertices.

[image]

Comment: I am interested in seeing the 5-vertex example you mention, primarily because I don't think one exists.  Gerharrd "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.29

Comment: Also, the pictures you have above suggest how to build two connected 12,4 examples.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.29

Comment: $5=6{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: It is the limit as $5\rightarrow 6.$

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  Edited it.