# Lower bound on number of $r$-regular graphs witn $n$ vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, lower-bounds

Consider the set of $r$-regular labeled graphs with $n$ vertices. There are results on its asymptotic size (see for instance [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there?newreg=07cd8b7d52694d84b6a05420cad93966) on MO).

Is there a known, explicit lower bound on that size, valid for any $r$ and $n$?

Comment: It is easy to see that once you have your $N(r, n_0)=a>1,$ then $N(r, k n_0) \geq a^k.$